# Can I use Unicode characters as regex patterns when using re2 library?

Tags: regex, search, re2

I want to know if the re2 library can handle all kind of special characters. I have to mention that I've done a lot of research on the net but didn't find anything that can make me understand. Thank you!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: I've worked with this yesterday; it works.

Comment: For example when I have the input StringPiece "München" and I want to search the pattern "ü" it gives me:
re2\re2.cc:173: Error parsing '(ⁿ)': invalid UTF-8
re2\re2.cc:768: Invalid RE2: invalid UTF-8

Comment: @paulotorrens Could you please share your solution? How did you work it out?